# Issues running javascript to update HTML and replay a counting animation using CSS keyframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iteration, keyframe

I am trying to build a simple web app using HTML/CSS and Javascript/JQuery that counts to 10 and animates and displays the numbers one after another.  I have the animations working well but I haven't been able to figure out the best way to update and rerun the animation in Javascript using JQuery.

All I want the program to do is run the animation "grow-number", then iterate the number in the h1 .anim tags and then display the same animation for each number in sequence starting from 1 to 10 so that the browser will show an animated counting sequence.

I tried using setInterval and using callbacks but I definitely did it wrong so I won't include those failures in my code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: normal 200px sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: orange;
}

.content-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /*opacity:0%;*/
}

.anim {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0;
  
  /*this animation SHOULD PROBABLY be called with javascript
  or jquery but I have NOT had any luck getting it to work and 
  iterating throug the numbers.  I uncommented here just to show 
  what it looks like in general*/
 
  animation: grow-number 4s 2s 10;
  /*animation-duration:4s;
    animation-name: grow-number;
    animation-delay:2s;
    animation-iteration-count:10;*/
}

@keyframes grow-number {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  19% {
    transform: scale(2.25);
    color: orange;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(2);
    color: blue;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(2);
    color: blue;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 100%;
    color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    color: orange;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Count to 10!</title>
  <!--jquery-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    //this needs to iterate and rerun the grow-number animation
    $(".anim").text(1);
    $(".anim").css({
      'animation': 'grow-number 4s 2s'
    });
  </script>
  <!--Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--STYLESHEETS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="countingdemo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content-area">
    <h1 class="anim">0</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Can someone help me with javascript/jquery code that works.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

Please wait somewhile  I adjusting the animation delay between countings.

```js
$('.anim').each(function () {
  $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
      Counter: 10
  }, {
      duration: 40000,

      step: function (now) {
          $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
      }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: normal 200px sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: orange;
}

.content-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 100vh;
  /*opacity:0%;*/
}

.anim {
  transform: scale(0);
  opacity: 0%;
  animation: grow-number 4s 2s 10 linear;
}
@keyframes grow-number {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: 0%;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 100%;
  }
  19% {
    transform: scale(2.25);
    color: orange;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(2);
    color: blue;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(2);
    color: blue;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 100%;
    color: orange;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(0);
    color: orange;
    opacity: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Count to 10!</title>
  <!--jquery-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!--STYLESHEETS-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="countingdemo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content-area">
    <h1 class="anim">0</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```